# Redirecting port 8080 to port 80 - how to add in /etc/sysconfig/iptables file?

Tags: centos, iptables, port-forwarding, centos7, jetty

On CentOS 7 Linux (acting as LAMP - and not "firewall/gateway") I have created [a custom systemd service](https://github.com/afarber/jetty-newbie/blob/master/WebsocketHandler/websocket-handler.service) for running embedded Jetty at port 8080 as user `nobody`:

```
[Unit]
Description=WebSocket Handler Service
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=nobody
Group=nobody
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -classpath '/usr/share/java/jetty/*' de.afarber.MyHandler 123.123.123.123:8080
ExecStop=/bin/kill ${MAINPID}
SuccessExitStatus=143

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

However I actually need the server to listen at the port 80 - so that WebSocket connections to it work even through corporate firewalls.

The Jetty document on [Setting Port 80 Access for a Non-Root User](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/setting-port80-access.html) suggests to run the following command:

```
# iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

Luckily I already use `iptables-services` package at my dedicated server and the current `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` file contains:

```
*filter
:INPUT DROP
:FORWARD DROP
:OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type any -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp -m multiport --dports 25,80,443,8080 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -m limit --limit 2/min --limit-burst 1 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
```

My problem is that I don't know the proper PREROUTING-syntax for the above file.

I have tried running the command above and then `iptables -S` in the hope that iptables will list the needed line for me - but that didn't happen.

**UPDATE:**

Unfortunately the following `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` file does not work:

```
*nat
:INPUT ACCEPT
:OUTPUT ACCEPT
:PREROUTING ACCEPT
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dst 123.123.123.123 --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080
COMMIT

*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT
:OUTPUT ACCEPT
:FORWARD ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type any -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -m state --state NEW -m multiport --dports 25,80,443,8080 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -m state --state NEW --dport 22 --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -m limit --limit 2/min --limit-burst 1 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -p tcp -m tcp --dst 123.123.123.123 --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
```

I need incoming HTTP-connections to 123.123.123.123:80
to be redirected to 123.123.123.123:8080 (where Jetty is listening
as user "nobody"), but for some reason this does not happen.

When I browse to http://123.123.123.123:8080 then I see Jetty response.

But when I browse to http://123.123.123.123 connection is refused.

Can anybody please spot the error for me?

Here is my current `nat` table:

```
# iptables -t nat -L
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
REDIRECT   tcp  --  anywhere             afarber.de           tcp dpt:http redir ports 8080

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Here is my current `filter` table:

```
# iptables -t filter -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp any
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp state NEW multiport dports smtp,http,https,webcache
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh flags:FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/SYN state NEW limit: avg 2/min burst 1

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             afarber.de           tcp dpt:webcache

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Here my `/etc/sysctl.conf` file:

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=1
```

Problem: requests to `-d 123.123.123.123 --dport 80` are not redirected to `8080`

**UPDATE 2:**

The line does not help either:

```
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp -i eth0:1 --dst 123.123.123.123 --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination :8080
```

the connection to `123.123.123.123:80` is still dropped

Comment: Please, DO NOT edit "/etc/sysconfig/iptables" manually. Just load all required rules using the "iptables", ensure that your app is working correctly and do "service iptables save". It will dump the currently running rules to the saved config.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be like this:

```
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [3:353]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [3:353]
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Jun 20 23:41:41 2016
```

Do you know how to do it the easy way?
I assume you have disabled the firewalld and installed iptables-services because you wanted your centos7 to work as centos6.

"/etc/sysconfig/iptables" is the file where iptables-services save the rules. You can edit it manualy, but there is no need to.
You can just enter any rules using the "iptables" command and then
"service iptables save" to save the currently active rules to the file.

You can also make is so that the rules will be saved every time the iptables service is restrted by setting here "/etc/sysconfig/iptables-config" IPTABLES_SAVE_ON_STOP and IPTABLES_SAVE_ON_RESTART

Comment: Thank you! Should I just append your text to my current `/etc/sysconfig/iptables`? I am confused that you have `*nat` and I have `*filter` - and wonder how to have both. Also I am worried if my computer starts forwarding and accepting  other packets since you have changed `INPUT/OUTPUT drop` to `accept`

Comment: Don't edit this file manually, it's hard and not needed. Just add your rules using "iptables", ensure that everything is working and then save the rules with "service iptables save". It will write this file automatically.

Comment: There are different tables in the iptables filter, nat and mangle and they are used for different purposes and have their own chains. Well, it's too much information for a single post to tell about them all. You can use "iptables-save" to view the current rules. Actually "service iptbles save" just writes the output of "iptbles-save" to the file.

Comment: Most likely you want DROP for the INPUT and ACCEPT for all other chains. These are called policies and can be set "iptables -t (table) -P (chain) (target)"

Comment: Please see my updated question, unfortunately I haven't been able to figure out the proper syntax yet. (And I have to be careful not to lock myself out of the dedicated server).

Comment: @AlexanderFarber with respect to that last comment, when I'm working on firewall rules remotely I like to start with `echo service iptables stop | at now + 15min` as root, knowing that if I lock myself out, I need only wait a few minutes and I can get back in.  If my change doesn't lock me out, I can use `atrm` to remove the job before it runs.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have finally figured it out - [the NAT HOWTO](http://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/NAT-HOWTO-6.html) says, that `-j REDIRECT` is just a shortcut for `-j DNAT` with destination address being the one of the interface:

> There is a specialized case of Destination NAT called redirection: it
>   is a simple convenience which is exactly equivalent to doing DNAT to
>   the address of the incoming interface.

But in my case that just can not work, because my CentOS 7 server has 4 IP addresses.

(I am sorry, that I haven't mentioned it, because I didn't think it would matter).

At `eth0` port 80 runs Apache (which can drop root rights).

And at `eth0:1` port 8080 runs Jetty (which can not drop root rights). But I need Jetty at port 80 (so that websockets work for corporate users behind proxies) and I want it to run as user "nobody".

And now I have figured out, how to redirect the incoming requests with `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` in /etc/sysctl.conf and with the following /etc/sysconfig/iptables:

```
*filter
:INPUT DROP
:OUTPUT ACCEPT
:FORWARD ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m multiport --dports 25,80,443,8080 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW --dport 22 --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -m limit --limit 2/min --limit-burst 1 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT

*nat
:INPUT ACCEPT
:OUTPUT ACCEPT
:PREROUTING ACCEPT
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT
-A PREROUTING -p tcp --dst 123.123.123.123 --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 123.123.123.123:8080
COMMIT
```